# launchtl: any way to disable a daemon after removing the plist file?

Tags: macos, launchd

I was trying to permanently disable a 3rd party daemon, so I deleted its plist file from /Library/LaunchDaemons-- and then I realized that I hadn't done a `launchctl unload` on it first; trying after the fact yields "No such file or directory/nothing found to unload".  And, of course the daemon is restartable, so when I kill it, it gets recreated.

I tried doing `launchctl list` in hopes of getting a label to use for `launchctl remove` but the daemon is no longer listed.

Short of rebooting, is there any way to get launchd to forget about the daemon and/or re-scan the configuration files?

Comment: The documentation is unclear, but `launchctl kill com.example.product` seems to work.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To see ALL the daemons currently running, you need to type:

```
sudo launchctl list
```

Or sort them to nicely separate `com.apple` ones:

```
sudo launchctl list | sort
```

And then you can remove it, for example:

```
sudo launchctl remove com.sassafras.KeyAccess.daemon
```

**Important Note** : If you don't want to get daemons on machine reboot, then please remove associated plist file.

Comment: Huh, I guess if you're not root, it only shows the daemons launched for/as the user?

Comment: This doesn't actually work for me. The entries come back on reboot.

Comment: @dimadima did you remove the associated plist file(s)? The commands provided by Dan only manipulate the current state (which is reset at next boot time to whatever is in /Library/LaunchDaemons).

Comment: @jhfrontz yup I've learned by now that you have to do that. Thank you.

Comment: @jhfrontz so the process should be `launchctl unload` then delete the `.plist` file is that correct?

Comment: @JohnnyQ  -- yes, I think that's the correct order.  Check out what bmike has to say here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/37195/10389

Comment: On Mac OS X Server, I found there was a LaunchDaemons directory tucked away inside Server.app itself path which was triggering Xcode. So for others, finding all of them with a simple: `find / -name LaunchDaemons 2> /dev/null` will list all the possible locations of the `.plist` files... HTH...

Comment: If it helps anyone, there are really always multiple unique lists available. All users in the directory have their own, although the root user and the logged in user are probably the most relevant. You can see all users who have processes with `sudo ps aux` or however you prefer then use `sudo launchctl asuser [UniqueID] launchctl list` to see the list for each user.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue today whereby the service continued to run under old label after the rename of the plist file. The service kept appearing in `ps` list and in `sudo launchctl list`.

The command that did the trick was `bootout`:

```
sudo launchctl bootout system/<label-obtained-from-launchctl-list>
```

Obviously, if the service is not in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` then one can do without `sudo` and `system/` prefix (seems that `system/` is a `domain` in launchd terminology).