# Cleaning up LaunchDaemons and LaunchAgents

Tags: macos, launchd

Trying to debug a slow-down of a Mac after a system upgrade, i would like to clean up LaunchDaemons and LaunchAgents, especially third-party ones. What it the proper way to do so?

Comment: there are some good threads like the following which provide info on this. Which methods do you already know ? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74779/launchtl-any-way-to-disable-a-daemon-after-removing-the-plist-file?rq=1

Comment: @anki, thanks for the link. I do not know any methods do be the right ones. Is it safe to just remove the files in LaunchDaemons and LaunchAgents?

Comment: I think this is an excellent question. I’ll make an answer later on how to avoid messing with agents and daemons until you’re sure that’s the issue.

Comment: Thanks @bmike, your answer will be valuable. However, i've already started messing with them because i'm too annoyed. I would still like to know how to clean them up, not just how to avoid messing with them.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the rush of close votes by pointing out multiple answers would be good to have here. (Or someone saying this needs need an edit)  IMO it’s clear and  answerable right now +1. Knowing how this work is valuable, and I’ll love to learn if we can also improve performance this way