# Remove .plist from /LaunchAgents

Tags: macos, terminal, launchd

Before I go to the issue, [I did find a similar thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37188/stopping-launchagents-and-daemons), but it's quite outdated and I'm not sure if it suits for me.

Around two years ago when I got my Mac, I decided to install Seagate Media Sync for my GoFlex device. Now, 3 years after purchase of the drive, I'd like to get rid of it and uninstall Media Sync from my computer. I got rid of the app but theres a 2nd app inside it's application support folder which keeps launch itself even if I quit the process.

I saw that one can run a specific terminal command to remove it, but I just wanted to make sure I have the correct instructions. The file is located inside the /Libary/LaunchAgents folder and named "com.seagate.mediasync.plist", some say it's just sufficient to remove the .plist file from there, but won't OS X constantly give a error because it has instructions to launch it? If it's better to just do it through terminal, I'd rather do that but I'm not certain which command that fits.. [According to this article](http://osxdaily.com/2011/03/08/remove-an-agent-from-launchd/)(also a bit outdated), you'll just need to run `launchctl remove com.anoying.service`, but it doesn't say anything about .plist files and more like folders..

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the command you mentioned, then delete the plist. That's all there is to it.

Comment: See http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25305/discussion-on-answer-by-william-t-froggard-remove-plist-from-launchagents