# How to Locate an App Running in the Background

Tags: macos, finder, applications, firewall, activity-monitor

My Mac is a work computer that used to have LANDesk installed. My admin ran a script that uninstalled it. However, when my machine starts I still get prompted to allow apps from LANDesk (vulscand, cba, proxyhost) to accept network connections. Neither my Admin nor I can figure out where these apps are hiding.

[image: vulscand landesk app notice]

When I run `sudo find ~ -iname "LANDesk"` or `sudo find ~ -iname "vulscand"` in terminal both return no results. I also do not see it listed in the OS X Activity Monitor app.

How can I find where "vulscand" is located on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a LaunchAgent? See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37188/stopping-launchagents-and-daemons) to stop. See [here](http://osxdaily.com/2011/03/08/remove-an-agent-from-launchd/) to remove.

If you want to find the actual file try [EasyFind](http://www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html). It'll find things that Spotlight does not, especially non-user oriented files.

Comment: It worked!! That is exactly where they were hiding. I'll add an answer with the exact steps I took.

Answer (score 0):

I finally [found the LANDesk system files](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202121) (and removed them) with finder:

- `/Library/LaunchAgents`
- `/Library/LaunchDaemons`
- `/Library/Preferences`
- `/Library/StartupItems`

To remove from launchctl:

```
sudo launchctl list | grep "name to find"
sudo launchctl remove "label.of.the.file"
```