# Disable LaunchDaemon services

Tags: launchd

I am trying to disable certain launchdaemon services. I am aware of the general procedure of doing this: `csrutil disable`

Following a reboot, the suggestion seems to just do a `launchctl unload /path/to/file/com.apple.file.plist`: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/37195

However, that doesnt prevent the service from spawning upon reboot.

Do I also need to run `launchctl remove`, or am I missing something?

Comment: Dare I ask why you're doing this? Are you sure that disabling parts of the OS is the best way to fix whatever problem you're having?

Comment: thanks. i cant answer that question. however i found out that the method below doesnt work for this file

Comment: I missed this question - apologies for asking for a new question. Let's see how we can sort this out best. I appreciate you working to get a searchable / correct answer up on the site.