# Removing launchdaemons in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons

Tags: launchd

I am trying to disable and remove some plist files. I originally tried doing this here, but it didnt work: [Disable LaunchDaemon services](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/444966/462281)

Disabling SIP, rebooting, disabling the plist file using `sudo launchctl unload -w /path/to/file.plist`, rebooting and enabling SIP and restarting doesnt work.

Disabling SIP, rebooting, adding the plist file with proper syntax to `/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/disabled.plist`, rebooting and enabling SIP, and rebooting doesnt work.

Does anybody know how to disable and/or remove LaunchDaemons in Macos Monterey?

There is a thread on how to do this here: [Stopping LaunchAgents and Daemons](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37188/stopping-launchagents-and-daemons/37195?noredirect=1#comment644096_37195)

But @bmike mentioned I should open a thread specifically for Macos Monterey, as there seems to be some changes in how Macos handles disabling services.

Comment: The real question is: what Daemons do you want to disable, and why? Perhaps there's a different method of inhibiting whatever behaviour you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. `csrutil` no longer works like before as explained here: https://eclecticlight.co/2019/06/19/what-is-sip-and-when-is-it-safe-to-turn-it-off/

There could be some workarounds, but seem to be much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I’ve modified automountd to reduce the RPC timeout so it doesn’t hang so long when my NFS server is unavailable.

By disabling SIP I’m able to unload the default automountd service and load my modified version (installed in /Library/LaunchDaemons/ and /usr/local/…) and it works as expected, but as soon as I reenable SIP the modification is ignored and I’m back to running with stock automountd.

So leaving SIP disabled is one way to accomplish this though obviously far from ideal. Apple should provide a better alternative.

(macOS 13.1)